# How do implement a named lifetime for a type inside of a trait that doesn't take a lifetime parameter?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement the r2d2::ManageConnection trait for a SQL Server. The issue that I'm running into is that the connection struct that I want to use for my implementation requires a lifetime parameter, but I can't figure out how to specify the lifetime.

Adding a named lifetime gives an error as expected.

```
 impl r2d2::ManageConnection for SQL_Server_Manager{
    type Connection = odbc::Connection<'a, AutocommitOn>;

type Connection = odbc::Connection<'a, AutocommitOn>;
                                   ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

Trying to use an unnamed lifetime also throws an error

```
type Connection = odbc::Connection<'_, AutocommitOn>;
                                    ^^ expected named lifetime parameter
```

And trying to add a named lifetime parameter to the trait throws an error

```
impl<'a> r2d2::ManageConnection<'a> for SQL_Server_Manager{
                                ^^ unexpected lifetime argument
```

What is the correct way to use a Type that requires a named lifetime parameter within a Trait implementation that doesn't take a lifetime parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles if you put a lifetime in the implementer type (`SQL_Server_Manager` in your case). Had to put a `PhantomData` inside to use this lifetime and avoid another compilation error.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e72aeb08ce185830c44dc6ac03918c4)

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    val: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Bar<'a> {
    pd: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a u32>,
}

trait Trait {
    type Connection;
    fn fun(&self, con: Self::Connection);
}

impl<'a> Trait for Bar<'a> {
    type Connection = Foo<'a>;
    fn fun(&self, con: Self::Connection) {
        println!("Implemented {}", con.val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = Bar::default();
    b.fun(Foo{ val:"FOO" }); // Implemented FOO
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The PhantomData type implementation is where I was stuck.